# iOS 11 show searchBar in navigation bar next to leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to get the new iOS-11 searchBar approach to work, but don't manage. The searchBar shows up, but is shown below the left bar button, instead of next to it:

[image]

It is the same in landscape mode. 
The code that I am using is:

```
self.searchResults = [[SearchResultsTable alloc] init];
self.searchResults.delegate = self;
searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResults];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.searchResults;
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(swapToListView:)];
if ([self.navigationItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setSearchController:)]) {
    // only available from IOS-11 onwards
    self.navigationItem.title = nil;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
    [self.navigationItem setSearchController:searchController];

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
}
```

The old code works fine on pre-iOS-11 systems, but has other problems on iOS-11, so I prefer to use the new approach. 
Anybody knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put search bar next to left navigation item then make your search bar `navigationItem`'s `titleView` regardless of iOS version, and don't use `UINavigationItem`'s `searchController` property.

Comment: Yes, that is the old approach that worked fine in iOS-10 and earlier. But there are major sizing issues with that approach in iOS-11. I got it to work in the end in iOS-11, but with a lot of manual sizing.